# problemas al mandar un arreglo del frontend al backen utilizando Jquery.Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Buen dia!

Estoy intentando mandar de mi frontend a mi backend un integer y una lista de strings

mi lista de strings la creo de la siguiente manera:

```
days = []

$('.content-checkbox ul li input:checked').each(function () {
    days.push($(this).data('name'))
});
```

este fragmento de codigo llena mi arreglo days de la siguiente manera

```
days = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles"]
```

Si debuggeo en el frontend el arreglo si se esta llenando de manera correcta, pero este llega null cuando lo recibo en mi backend

los datos los mando de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '@Url.Action("buscarEcuacion", "Ecuaciones")',
       content: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       data: {
              idStore: 12,
              days: days
       },
       success: function (data) {

       }
});
```

en mi backend recibo sin problemas la variable idStore, pero la lista siempre llega nula

este es el codigo de mi backend:

```
public ActionResult buscarEcuacion(int idStore, List<string> days){
   return Json("");
}
```

si cambio de tipo la variable days por string, integer o algun tipo primitivo llegan las dos cariables sin problemas

¿Cual es la forma correcta de mandar mi array al backend?
¿Me falta agregar algun valor en el content del AJAX para poder recibir la lista?

Comment: MVC realiza el binding de acuerdo a los nombres de los parámetros y el tipo. Entonces podrías intentar `public ActionResult buscarEcuacion(int idStore, string[] days){
   return Json("");
}`

Otra opción es hacer un `var daysJson= JSON.stringify(days);` y enviar el daysJson en data y en el controller recibirlo tal cual esta

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Luisa. Ya habia intentado cambiando la lista por un arreglo en el backend y no me funciono queria evitar usar JSON.stringify.
agradezco mucho tu ayuda!